# My questions marked a favorite but still down votes? Is this unusual behavior?

Tags: discussion, bug, moderators, down-votes, bookmarks

More of my questions have been marked as favorite but are still down voted to the point of a question ban. Can a handful of people out of thousands down vote a user into a question ban?

https://engineering.stackexchange.com/users/4139/muze

Comment: Relatively new users only need a couple of downvotes to get question banned, yes. Favourited questions have nothing to do with it, that's a different metric unrelated to question bans.

Comment: Where relatively new is based on rep, I think. You got a lot of posts and not a lot of score. Not sure what's going on here, but some of your questions could've been phrased much better.

Comment: @Mast I would be grateful for any help on the phasing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Favorite" is a bad name.  It's just a bookmark.  Marking a question "favorite" really only means that person wants to be able to get back to it easily in the future.  It does not necessarily mean they like it or that it is one of their favorite questions, as the name unfortunately implies.

Votes are the mechanism for passing judgement on a question.  Marking a question for easy future reference has nothing to do with that.